# Trying to load data from a textfield to highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am populating a highchart data via JS, the data is coming from a textbox on the page, this content is dynamically replaced:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myvar = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;

    Highcharts.chart('piechart2', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{ name: 'Permits', data: myvar }]
    });
};
```

My textfield:

```
<input name="TextBox1" value="[{"name":"Closed","y":1},{"name":"Rejected","y":1}]" id="TextBox1" type="text">
```

Currently when the JS is executed the chart does not render, I believe it is because the myvar which is used for the data is not copied correctly. If I replace 'myvar' with the contents of the textbox the chart is rendered correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try parsing it to JSON using JSON.parse(myvar), its going as a string right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the string that you're setting value you to there is an example input? It looks like you're going for a stringified json kind of thing? If so, you need one kind of quote around the whole thing, and then use the other kind of quote for the internal quotes, like so:

```
value='[{"name":"Closed","y":1},{"name":"Rejected","y":1}]'
```

Then I'm guessing you'll need to de-stringify it before you give it to high charts

```
var myvar = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
myvar = JSON.parse(myvar)
```

This assumes that you're expecting valid json to be typed into your text box, which might not be a good assumption. Another solution might be to have mutiple inputs, one that takes each value you need, and then you can stick them all together into a properly formatted object.

Comment: Many thanks Steve, that now works as expected. That was driving me crazy!